# Megacreds farming In Strikefleet Omega

Tags: strikefleet-omega

In [Strikefleet Omega](http://harebrained-schemes.com/strikefleet/) what is the best fleet layout to farm megacreds in survival mode?

Right now my layout to farm Megacreds is like following:

- mining carrier
- commander carrier and 2 star fighter carriers with fighters circulating around other carriers
- interceptor carrier with fighters circulating around other carriers
- bomber carrier with fighters circulating around other carriers, and dispatched toward heavy enemy when they arrive.
- artillery ship for groups of enemies and Alien Credit Saucer that drops Megacreds

All ships are level 3 Alloy-unlockable ships. I have farmed enough Alloy to purchase every Alloy upgrade.

Now I farmed enough Megacreds to unlock the Tesla class Gunship, so I am thinking to replace a bomber carrier with a Tesla class, but I found aiming is a little hard as I usually play survival farming in fast forward mode. Is there a better fleet to farm Megacreds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After farmed enough Megacreds to fully upgrade the fleet, I can say Tesla class can't replace bombers or interceptor if the goal is to stay over wave 250, but may very well work if the goal is to farm Megacreds until wave 200.

In fact a more expandable carrier is the interceptor. The enemy bombers can be shot down using Tesla class quite easily. When the fast enemy destroyers sneak in, the interceptor then becomes increasing necessary, because Tesla may not be recharged in time. The command ship may not survive long enough to see the fast enemy destroyers come in groups, so a 3 Tesla class layout may work for enemy bombers and destroyers for farming purposes (see below).

The problem of a 3 Tesla class layout are the Big Bertha and alien fighters. Although Teslas can shot down the red Big Berthas with ease, the black Big Berthas around wave 250 can't be taken down even with 3 Tesla classes, which means bombers are a must if you want to pass wave 250, and that is with good aiming at alien fighters as they outnumber the star fighters before that. A fully upgraded artillery would be a big help around wave 200 as the splash damage is more effective against the large number of small fighters.

For Megacreds farming purposes, wave 200 is really the goal here. After that the difficulty gets harder (a lot more actions per minute) but the rate of Megacreds drops does not increase. So at the end, the fleet layout I used looks exactly like the one I asked to improve, except the artillery is replaced by a Tesla class after wave 100.